# Who should customize appearance of a CustomUIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, factory

What I would like to ask here is a design question.

I have a CustomUIViewController that handle some subviews inside the controller view.

These two views are logically distinct and have different roles:

- The first subview contains the UIControl objects the user can
  interact with (Game Controls).
- The second subview just shows the game progresses.

The problem is that I need to have multiple Game Controls implementations (let's say two, that can be graphically totally different) and let the user choose the one he prefers.

My question is: will it be considered a good practice to have the CustomUIViewController's code coupled with both the Game Controls implementations (included the graphic assets to use to customize the appearance of each one)? Or would it be better if the appearance setup of the Game Control views is handled by another object (a factory, a delegate or something similar)?

Can you suggest any pattern that can help to handle a use case like this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The controller would usually control that. You could alternatively have the controller monitor the change in user choice and then set a flag on the game controls view. That flag dictates which graphics are used when it displays (and the flag changing causes a redisplay / change of image resources) depending on how you have currently allocated the knowledge about the image names.

Comment: @Wain: Which one is to be considered a best practice with the knowledge about the image names: embedding it inside the CustomUIViewController or rather put it into the specialized Game Control view?

Comment: I'd opt for he controller knowing the image names. I wouldn't say either was a hard best practice. So long as the structure is sensible and consistent then the view can specify its default images and offer users (the controller) the option of changing them. If the view presents a couple of display styles then it can manage it all. Think about `UITableView` and what it makes available...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create separate classes for two views which you are going to add on `CustomUIViewController`.
You can then add whatever components and functionalities you want in respective classes.
It would be easy to understand the code, you will also feel easy in case you wish to add some extended functionalities to particular subview.
Don't put everything in the same class, you might end up messing up the things.

If possible always try to follow [MVC Architecure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html)

Comment: I totally agree with you. The two Game Control views will be two distinct classes. Their internal structure will be totally different but each Game Control class will expose the same interface to CustomUIViewController. But who should have the knowledge about the image names? Should I embed it into the specialized Game Control view or into the CustomUIViewController that contains it?

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the 2 UIView you are trying to use so that you can have 2 custom views than add to your viewcontroller.

By doing this you have a benefit of getting touch events on your custom UIView implementation and it will be an easier approach then putting everything in the same class.